# Relative time in weeks is not supported in day.js

Tags: javascript, dayjs

I just migrated from moment.js to day.js.
The migration was very smooth but day.js is not providing relative time in weeks.
What I was doing in moment.js

```
       // Round relative time evaluation down
       moment.relativeTimeRounding(Math.floor);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 24);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 7);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('w', 4);
       moment.relativeTimeThreshold('M', 12);
```

Using the above relative time config, I got the desired output like `2 weeks ago`.

After migration to day.js, now my config is

```
    const thresholds = [
      { l: 's', r: 1 },
      { l: 'ss', r: 59, d: 'second' },
      { l: 'm', r: 1 },
      { l: 'mm', r: 59, d: 'minute' },
      { l: 'h', r: 1 },
      { l: 'hh', r: 23, d: 'hour' },
      { l: 'd', r: 1 },
      { l: 'dd', r: 6, d: 'day' },
      { l: 'w', r: 1},
      { l: 'ww', r: 4, d: 'week'},
      { l: 'M', r: 1 },
      { l: 'MM', r: 11, d: 'month' },
      { l: 'y', r: 1 },
      { l: 'yy', d: 'year' },
    ];
```

With above config in day.js I got the following error.

```
core.js?7d7a:4073 ERROR TypeError: v is not a function
    at Object.n.fromToBase (VM15721 relativeTime.js:82)
    at i (VM15721 relativeTime.js:32)
    at M.n.from (VM15721 relativeTime.js:93)
    at M.n.fromNow (VM15721 relativeTime.js:103)
```

When I remove

```
      { l: 'w', r: 1},
      { l: 'ww', r: 4, d: 'week'},
```

and change the day's threshold to 30,

from day.js config, then it works fine and I got output like `13 days ago`.

**So, my question is, is there any workaround to get output in weeks instead of days?**

Comment: Its called days.js for a reason :)

Comment: Did you find a way to show weeks?

Comment: Nope (we dropped showing week(s)), but I'll check if day.js updated to show the weeks and test the anwer by @metalunicorn as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

updateLocale must be added

```
dayjs.extend(updateLocale);
dayjs.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
      future: 'in %s',
      past: '%s ago',
      s: 'a few seconds',
      m: 'a minute',
      mm: '%d minutes',
      h: 'an hour',
      hh: '%d hours',
      d: 'a day',
      dd: '%d days',
      w: '%d week',
      ww: '%d weeks',
      M: 'a month',
      MM: '%d months',
      y: 'a year',
      yy: '%d years',
    },
  });
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, as it just ignored `w` and `ww` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since day.js doesn't support weeks in the `relativeTime` plugin by default, we must write an extension using [additional token processing](https://day.js.org/docs/en/customization/relative-time#additional-token-processing).

> If a locale requires additional processing for a token, it can set the token as a function with the following signature instead of a string. The function should return a string.
>
> ```js
> relativeTime: {
>  ...,
>  yy: function (number, withoutSuffix, key, isFuture) {
>    return string;
>  }
> }
> ```

Here is how I used it to write the weeks notation.

```js
dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
dayjs.extend(updateLocale);

dayjs.updateLocale("en", {
  relativeTime: {
    future: "in %s",
    past: "%s ago",
    s: "0m", // hide seconds
    ss: "0m",
    m: "1m",
    mm: "%dm",
    h: "1h",
    hh: "%dh",
    d: "1d",
    dd: function (number: number) {
      if (number >= 7) {
        return `${Math.round(number / 7)}w`
      }
      return `${number}d`;
    },
    M: "1m",
    MM: "%dm",
    y: "1y",
    yy: "%dy",
  },
});
```